# maxRequestLength and Message: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service

Tags: .net

I have set my maxRequestLength to the max length in my Web.Config on my IIS 6 ASP.NET web app and I'm trying to read in a file of around 5 or 6 megabytes when I get the following error:

> Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.

Is there any vital configuration I'm missing or any particular way I should be reading in my file? At the moment I'm using the 'ReadAllBytes' method.

Everything online seems to suggest it is to do with the configuration and nothing more but I have ensured this is correct and the problem still persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Ian

Comment: Where does "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service." come from?  If it's an exception, please provide the exception detail.